# Loading JSON data in Datatable takes too long

Tags: laravel, vue.js, axios, bootstrap-vue

I'm using Laravel and Vue for a project I'm working on. Within my dashboard I'm using BootstrapVue's datatable named B-table, which receives JSON data from my API.

The API currently only returns 1 user, however it takes quite some time to load it even though it's just 1 row. I created this GIF to show you it's loading time when refreshing the webpage:

[image]

I'm using Axios to receive data from my API, I'm very curious what's causing it to be this slow. Here is my code:

```
<template>
    <div>
        <div id="main-wrapper" class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-12">
                    <hr>
                    <b-table busy.sync="true" show-empty striped hover responsive :items="users" :fields="fields" :filter="filter" :current-page="currentPage" :per-page="perPage" @refreshed="verfris">
                        <template slot="actions" slot-scope="data">
                            <a class="icon" href="#"><i class="fas fa-eye"></i></a>
                            <a class="icon" href="#"><i class="fas fa-pencil-alt"></i></a>
                            <a class="icon"><i class="fas fa-trash"></i></a>
                        </template>
                    </b-table>
                    <b-pagination :total-rows="totalRows" :per-page="perPage" v-model="currentPage" class="my-0 pagination-sm" />
                </div>

            </div>

        </div>
    </div>
</template>
<script>
    export default {

        data() {
            return {
                users: [],
                filter: null,
                currentPage: 1,
                perPage: 10,
                totalRows: null,
                selectedID: null,
                fields: [
                    {
                        key: 'id',
                        sortable: true
                    },
                    {
                        key: 'name',
                        sortable: true
                    },
                    {
                        key: 'email',
                        sortable: true
                    },
                    {
                        key: 'actions'
                    }

                ],
            }
        },
        mounted() {
            this.getResults();
        },
        methods: {
            // Our method to GET results from a Laravel endpoint
            getResults(ctx, callback) {
                axios.get('/api/users')

                    .then(response => {
                        this.users = response.data;
                        this.totalRows = response.data.length;
                        return this.users;
                    });
            }
        },

    }
</script>
```

And the JSON data my API returns:

```
[
    {
        "id": 1,
        "name": "test",
        "email": "user@user.nl",
        "email_verified_at": null,
        "created_at": "2018-09-28 16:04:36",
        "updated_at": "2018-09-28 16:04:36"
    }
]
```

What can I do to solve this loadtime issue?

*UPDATE: I'm hosting it on Ubuntu within VirtualBox, maybe it would be important to any of you guys.*

UPDATE response time of the request to my API:

[image]

Comment: What's the response time when you're loading the api directly from your browser? Perhaps, could be your hardware?

Comment: Thanks for your reply Paul. While I can't request the API in my browser, I get request times around 195ms when I send requests in Postman.

Comment: Open up the network tab on the developer console in-browser and check to see what the response times are.

Comment: Should have thought of that, I updated the topic with a screenshot of the response time. @DerekPollard

Comment: Main reasons should be , you are using ubuntu with virtual box and memory your os consume and soon , If you can share the code it would be easy to tell (laravel).

also you dont need to  return this.users as you have already assigned the values to this.users :)

Comment: I made a git repository of it, hope you can help me out Raza. https://github.com/amirakbulut/ledberg

Comment: Also, when I run it on localhost using Xampp it response time is just 200-300ms, but when on Ubuntu using Virtualbox, its around 1.25sec.

Answer (score 0):

From your comment in the post, I guess you already figured out what wrong? i.e. Something is funky about your VirtualBox setup?

I cloned your app and it only took 88ms to load on my Mac.  [image: Proof]

BTW, your code does not run out of the box.  Had to fix and bypass a couple things to get it to run.  I would also suggest you install [laravel-debugbar](https://github.com/barryvdh/laravel-debugbar) to help with debug in laravel.